# SpriteKit tunneling when user moves node

Tags: swift, swiftui, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have a question about (continuous) SpriteKit collision detection.

I have a SwiftUI/SpriteKit project in which balls fall from above and the user tries to catch the balls with a cup.

The user moves the cup horizontally by dragging their finger.

The physics work well with one exception -- the balls properly collide with each other, and with the cup, **except when the cup is being moved**.

When the cup is being moved by the user, the balls that had fallen into the cup tunnel right through the side of the cup.

Again, the balls collide with the cup correctly, and settle in the cup, except when the cup is moving.

**EDIT: I added `categoryBitMask` and `collisionBitMask` to both the balls and the cup, as suggested in the comments. But the problem remains.**

```
enum CollisionTypes: UInt32 {
    case ball = 1
    case cup = 2
}
```

The cup:

```
func cup() -> SKSpriteNode {
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let cupNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cup.png")
        let cupNodeChild = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cupOutline.png")

        cupNode.position = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width*0.5, y: MainData.cupY)
        cupNode.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 0.25, height: screenSize.width * 0.35)
        cupNode.name = "cup"
        cupNode.zPosition = 1.0 

        cupNodeChild.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 0.25, height: screenSize.width * 0.35)
        cupNodeChild.name = "cupCollisionNode"
        cupNodeChild.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: cupNodeChild.texture!, size: CGSize(width: screenSize.width * 0.25, height: screenSize.width * 0.35))
        cupNodeChild.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
        cupNodeChild.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        cupNodeChild.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

        cupNodeChild.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.cup.rawValue
        cupNodeChild.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.ball.rawValue

        cupNode.addChild(cupNodeChild)

        return cupNode
    }
```

The balls:

```
func initializeBalls(screenWidth: CGFloat, screenHeight: CGFloat) {
        MainData.balls.removeAll()
        
        for i in 0..<numOfBalls {
            let radius = screenWidth * 0.02
            let x = screenWidth * CGFloat.random(in: 0...1)
            let y = screenHeight
            let ballNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball.png")
            
            ballNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            ballNode.size = CGSize(width: radius*2, height: radius*2)
            ballNode.name = "ball\(i)"
            
            ballNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
            ballNode.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
            ballNode.physicsBody?.mass = 5.0
            ballNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            
            ballNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.ball.rawValue
            ballNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.cup.rawValue

            ballNode.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ballNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask
            
            ballNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.1
            
            MainData.balls.append((
                x: x,
                y: y,
                radius: radius,
                img: "ball.png",
                node: ballNode
            ))
        }
    }
```

Here's how I move the cup, in my `GameScene`:

```
func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
     let action = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: pos.x, y: MainData.cupY), duration: 0)
        
     cupNode?.run(action)
}
```

Why is this tunneling happening, and how do I avoid it?

Comment: That's obviously because you are not setting the collision bit mask to any of the participants in your show.

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I stated in my question, the balls and cup collide correctly except when the cup is being moved.

Comment: At which lines are you setting the collision bit mask to ballNode and cupNode, then?

Comment: How can collisionBitMask be the problem when the balls/cup DO COLLIDE CORRECTLY when the cup is stationary?

Comment: The collision and the contact are two different physical occurrences in Sprite Kit. You are probably talking about the physical contact.  I'm not.

Comment: Ok, then could you please post an answer with an example of how to set collisionBitMask?

Comment: @ElTomato According to the documentation for collisionBitMask: "The default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set)."

Comment: I would rather see it as code.